# Count of values which appear more than once in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel column I have values as such:

**ID**
a
a
a
b
c
c
d
e

I would like to return the count of ids which occur twice or more. In this case answer is 2 (a,c).

**Constraints:**

1. No helper cols or one at most(There are a ton of other filters to be added to the countifs which are not relevant to the question,adding helpers would mean 12+ extra columns, one for each month)

2.No VBA ( UDF is ok)

3.Formula result in single cell.

The current formula which I have tried:
=COUNTIFS(F13:F22,COUNTIF(F13:F22,">=2"))
gives me 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would double values always be in sequence?

Comment: No, but any type of sorting can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm with no specific order of values, try:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9)>1,1/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9),0))
```

Enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Another variant would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9)>1)/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9))
```

With the advantage you won't have to enter as array.

[image]

Would you choose to add criteria I believe that the second formula is a bit more userfriendly adding them in, like so (edited your sample data a little to show):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B9=1)*(C2:C9="x")*(COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9)>1)/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this once I'm home. Is it possible to change the countif to countifs to include multiple criteria for other columns?